# I have errors regarding positional arguments which I dont quite understand. Help please

Tags: flutter, tabs, provider

I am working on a community app which has series of Tabs on the bottom bar. I've been able to implement the major code and all tabs are working except the last. It is meant to show user profile on click but I'm getting errors due to positional arguments and I cant quite wrap my head around the solution. Here is the bit of code giving me the error(extracted from my main.dart file):

```
providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<AppState>(create: (_) => AppState()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthState>(create: (_) => AuthState()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<FeedState>(create: (_) => FeedState()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ChatState>(create: (_) => ChatState()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<SearchState>(create: (_) => SearchState()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<NotificationState>(
            create: (_) => NotificationState()),
        ***ChangeNotifierProvider<ProfileState>(create: (_) => ProfileState()),***
      ],
```

I'm getting the errors on the last line there: 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.
Try adding the missing arguments.

Here is a portion of my code from Profile State which I believe is most relevant:

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart' as dabase;

class ProfileState extends ChangeNotifier {
  ProfileState(this.profileId) {
    databaseInit();
    userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
    _getloggedInUserProfile(userId);
    _getProfileUser(profileId);
  }

  /// This is the id of user who is logegd into the app.
  String userId;

  /// Profile data of logged in user.
  UserModel _userModel;
  UserModel get userModel => _userModel;

  dabase.Query _profileQuery;
  StreamSubscription<Event> profileSubscription;

  /// This is the id of user whose profile is open.
  final String profileId;

  /// Profile data of user whose profile is open.
  UserModel _profileUserModel;
  UserModel get profileUserModel => _profileUserModel;

  bool _isBusy = true;
  bool get isbusy => _isBusy;
  set loading(bool value) {
    _isBusy = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  databaseInit() {
    try {
      if (_profileQuery == null) {
        _profileQuery = kDatabase.child("profile").child(profileId);
        profileSubscription = _profileQuery.onValue.listen(_onProfileChanged);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      cprint(error, errorIn: 'databaseInit');
    }
  }

  bool get isMyProfile => profileId == userId;

  /// Fetch profile of logged in  user
  void _getloggedInUserProfile(String userId) async {
    kDatabase
        .child("profile")
        .child(userId)
        .once()
        .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.value != null) {
        var map = snapshot.value;
        if (map != null) {
          _userModel = UserModel.fromJson(map);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  /// Fetch profile data of user whoose profile is opened
  void _getProfileUser(String userProfileId) {
    assert(userProfileId != null);
    try {
      loading = true;
      kDatabase
          .child("profile")
          .child(userProfileId)
          .once()
          .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.value != null) {
          var map = snapshot.value;
          if (map != null) {
            _profileUserModel = UserModel.fromJson(map);
            Utility.logEvent('get_profile');
          }
        }
        loading = false;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      loading = false;
      cprint(error, errorIn: 'getProfileUser');
    }
  }
```

Please what's the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You have the this.profileId as an argument in the ProfileState constructor, and in the providers in the main file you didnt provide the needed argument for the constructor. That's why you are getting this error I believe.

[flutter](/questions/tagged/flutter)[dart](/questions/tagged/dart)